# Scope of a function works only when defined in this format not in other. Explanation needed,

Tags: javascript, function

As described in MDN Javascript.
This code gives output as 25.

```
console.log(square(5));
function square(n) { return n*n }
```

But this code doesn't.

```
console.log(square(5));
square = function (n) {
  return n * n;
}
```

Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference is `function square` is defined at parse time whereas `square = function` is defined at run time. `square` is a variable which holds anonymous function. `function square(){}` always executed at `global context`

To get the better understanding, Read about [`variable hoisting in JavaScript`](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092)

To make it work, define the variable which holds the function expression before calling it.

```js
var square = function(n) {
  return n * n;
}
alert(square(5));
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try putting function defincation first**

```js
square = function (n) {
  return n * n;
}
console.log(square(5));
```